# Creating DDL of partitioned table / database in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, partitioning

Honestly, I'm weak in partitioning and still learning it.

**scenario**: I have a data warehouse consisting of partitioned tables in production server (SQL Server 2014 EE)

**aim**: to create new database in separate server(new dev SQL Server 2014 DevEdition) consisting of partitioned tables only (no data) with changes in filename, size, maxsize, autogrowth.

**What I tried**:

1. `Generating script` of whole database. But it comes with pre-defined filename, size, maxsize and filegrowth for partitions. I can't manually edit it all due to number of partitions !

eg:

```
NAME = N'Daily20170501', FILENAME = N'G:\SQLDB\Data\Daily\Daily20170501.ndf' , SIZE = 56256KB , MAXSIZE = 204800000KB , FILEGROWTH = 102400KB ), 
 FILEGROUP [Daily20170502]
```

2. Create a backup of prod and restore in new dev. But this also doesn't help me.

I want to change filename, reduce size, maxsize and filegrowth of new tables. How can I achieve this task?

Request for a little detailed explanation as I'm still learning partitioning.

Comment: *"I want to change filename, reduce size, maxsize and filegrowth of new tables"* these properties are from the files in each filegroup, which is different from the partitioned table. A partitioned table is assigned to N different filegroups, each filegroup can hold multiple partitions of the same table and also different tables.

Comment: @EzLo: That's right. So I have around 400 filegroups. I want to edit their properties. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: There's no automatic way I know of to do this massively, your best bet would be using a text editor with regular expressions to modify each option. You could also parse the command and load the parameters to a table to update them with SQL if you are fluent in it.

Comment: Try posing in dba.stackexchange.com, maybe a pro dba has a tool for you.

Comment: I managed to do it temporarily using excel :) Still, I was expecting something more structured. Will post on dba.stackexchange. Thanks